# ruby rails dynamic css class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page where I called my shared component

```
<%= render 'headers', positionRight: true, ...}  %>
```

I want to make `positionRight` parameter as an optional parameter. In my shared component I couldn't get the css working

```
<section class=<%= (defined? positionRight && positionRight) ? "custom-css-class" : "" %>>
```

It looks like it always fall into the empty css class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above scenario can be handled the following way:

```
<% positionRight||= false %>
<section class=<%= positionRight ? "custom-css-class" : "" %>>
```

and then

```
<%= render 'headers', positionRight: true, ...}  %>
OR
<%= render 'headers', ...}  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect it to always give you `custom-css-class`. `(defined? positionRight && positionRight)` to always evaluate to `'expression'` regardless of what value (if any) `positionRight` has. Remember that `defined?` isn't a method call, it is a keyword and you're giving it an expression.

You'd be better off saying something like this at the top of your ERB file:

```
<%
  if !defined? positionRight
    positionRight = false
  end
%>
```

so that `positionRight` will always have a value and then

```
<section class=<%= positionRight ? 'custom-css-class' : '' %>>
```

when you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

First, `defined? something` will return type of something, and in this case something is `positionRight && positionRight` that mean this is an "expression", so your logic will fall into "custom-css-class" not empty css as you said, since `"expression" ?`  will always fall into truthy case.

Second, your logic just has 2 cases: true or the rest (false, nil), so no matter you set `positionRight` (true, false) or not set, the code below should ok:

```rb
positionRight ? "custom-css-class" : ""
```

Last but not least, in case you want more than 3 cases: `positionRight` is defined: true or false or even nil, and `positionRight` is not defined, then you now could use `defined?` as below code:

```rb
defined?(positionRight) ? (positionRight ? "css-align-right" : "css-align-left") : ""
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view add this as first row of file:

```rb
<% positionRight ||= false %>
<% section_class = positionRight ? 'custom-css-class' : '' %>
```

And now you can use your `section_class` anywhere in the file:

```rb
<section class='<%= section_class %>' >...
```

Please, pay attention to definition of class in `section` element. You have to use single quotes, otherwise if your class name will include spaces, result html element will be invalid.

As well, pay attention that you variable positionRight named not in ruby style (in ruby usually they uses snakecase => `position_right` would be more semantic)